# CSS TABS on HOVER

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

Is there any way that i can manipulate this code so that once you hover over the tab it will be made the active/ default/ current tab selection?

So that even if you scroll down the page and come back up it won't go back to Tab1?

http://jsfiddle.net/QA5Zp/

Ideally I need Pure CSS only :)

- See Code:

#### Most Recent Posts

```
<li><a href='http://www.kamikazemusic.com/quick-tips/key-metrics-google-analytics/' title='5 key metrics you should know from Google Analytics'>
5 key metrics you should know from Google Analytics</a></li> 
<li><a href='http://www.kamikazemusic.com/general-stuff/ie6/' title='We all dislike IE6 but lets not be childish'>
We all dislike IE6 but lets not be childish</a></li> 
<li><a href='http://www.kamikazemusic.com/general-stuff/smiling-appliance/' title='Smiling Appliance'>
Smiling Appliance</a></li> 
<li><a href='http://www.kamikazemusic.com/quick-tips/trading-eye-search-fixes/' title='Trading Eye Search Fixes (v5)'>
Trading Eye Search Fixes (v5)</a></li> 
<li><a href='http://www.kamikazemusic.com/web-design/beautiful-email-newsletters/' title='Check me out on Beautiful Email Newsletters (BEN)'>
Check me out on Beautiful Email Newsletters (BEN)</a></li> 
<li><a href='http://www.kamikazemusic.com/portfolio/mopay-flash-and-gif-banners/' title='Mopay Flash and GIF Banners'>
Mopay Flash and GIF Banners</a></li> 
<li><a href='http://www.kamikazemusic.com/portfolio/stamford-clothiers/' title='Stamford Clothiers'>
Stamford Clothiers</a></li> 
<li><a href='http://www.kamikazemusic.com/web-development/tradingeye-query-string-search/' title='TradingEye show search query string in URL'>
TradingEye show search query string in URL</a></li> 
<li><a href='http://www.kamikazemusic.com/quick-tips/basics-html-email-newsletters/' title='The 10 Basics of HTML Email Newsletters'>
The 10 Basics of HTML Email Newsletters</a></li> 
</ul>
```

#### Most Popular Posts

Why we should all be forward thinking

Mopay Flash and GIF Banners

Stamford Clothiers

TradingEye show search query string in URL

The 10 Basics of HTML Email Newsletters

5 key metrics you should know from Google Analytics

We all dislike IE6 but lets not be childish

Smiling Appliance

Trading Eye Search Fixes (v5)

Check me out on Beautiful Email Newsletters (BEN)

- CSS Stylesheet:

body{
            font : 12px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial serif;
        }
        .clearboth{
            clear:both;
        }

```
    #csstabs li{ padding:2px;}

    #csstabs{ position:relative; width:500px; height:290px; }
    #csstabs h3{ padding:5px; height:30px; text-align:center; cursor:hand; display:block;       font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; margin:0;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    }


    .tabcontent{
        padding:10px 0 0 40px;
        width:100%;
        background:#fff;
        border:1px solid #000;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:40px;
        height:230px;
        display:block;
        margin:0;
    }


    #tab1 .tabcontent{
        z-index:2;
        background:#fff;
    }
    #tab1 h3{
        z-index:3;
        width:150px;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        cursor:hand;
        background:#fff;
    }


    #tab2 .tabcontent{
        z-index:1; 
        opacity:0;
    }
    #tab2 h3{
        width:150px;
        position:absolute;
        left:180px;
        top:0;
        cursor:hand;
    }

    #csstabs:hover h3, #tabs:focus h3, #tabs:active h3{
        background:none;
        z-index:0;
        }

    #csstabs:hover .tabcontent, #tabs:focus .tabcontent, #tabs:active .tabcontent{
        z-index:0;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition : opacity .75s ease-in;
        }

    #tab1:hover h3,#tab1:focus h3,#tab1:active h3{z-index:4;background:#fff;}
    #tab1:hover .tabcontent,#tab1:focus .tabcontent,#tab1:active .tabcontent{   z-index:3;  background:#fff; opacity:1; -webkit-transition : opacity 2s ease-in;}

    #tab2:hover h3,#tab2:focus h3,#tab2:active h3{z-index:4;background:#fff;}
    #tab2:hover .tabcontent,#tab2:focus .tabcontent,#tab2:active .tabcontent{   z-index:3;  background:#fff; opacity:1; -webkit-transition : opacity 2s ease-in;}
```

Comment: Can't be done using css only if you expect user to move away and maintain state. Otherwise doing tabs with javascript is not hard to find code for in a web search

Comment: You gonna need a cookie

Comment: I have just found this code, which uses on 'CLICK' method, is there anyway to achieve this 'On Hover/ Mouseover' the tab?

http://jsfiddle.net/QA5Zp/1/

I think they are using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the fiddle you posted (with jquery), replacing click with mouseenter should give what you want [fiddle with mouseenter](https://jsfiddle.net/QA5Zp/25/)

```
$('.tabbox').on('mouseenter', function(){
   $('.tabbox').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Since you are new to jquery, let me explain what this does as well.

```
$('.tabbox').on('mouseenter', function(){
```

This selects all elements with class 'tabbox', and adds a 'mouseenter' event handler, which is the function that follows. So every time the 'mouseenter' event happens, the function does it's thing.

```
$('.tabbox').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

The first thing it does when the function is called, is it selects all elements with class 'tabbox' and removes the class 'active' from them. Then it adds the class 'active' to 'this', 'this' is a reference to the object which was 'mouseentered'.

Comment: awesome ! - WHAT A STAR :D


Thank You So Much

Comment: HOW WOULD I then go on to add another two tabs?
For some reason it is not working :/

Comment: Should work the same way, you probably have a mistake in your css somewhere, do you have an updated fiddle? Can try to look at it later